# NVD3 - lineWithFocusChart - disable auto sort for x-axis labels/ticks

Tags: nvd3.js

I'm creating a Line Chart with View Finder in nvd3 and my problem is that even if specify my ticks with the help of an (unsorted) array and `.tickValues` the result is again sorted.
To be more clear:  my array contains numbers like `(49,50,51,52,1,2,3,4)`. I would like to have the x-axis in exactly this order. But the result is a sorted version `(1,2,3,4,49,50,51,52)`.
So I assume that there is some kind of auto sorting, even if I use `.tickValues`?! How can I disable this sorting?

Here an example code:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

    // chart.transitionDuration(500);

    chart.xAxis.tickValues(x_labels_array);
    chart.x2Axis.tickValues(x_labels_array);

    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
    chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
    d3.select('#chart svg').datum(createData()).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Comment: Your edit has been rolled back by @RamchandraApte before I even had a chance to fix your error, but this just goes to show that it was a poor edit.

Comment: @shabeer90, if *you* look at the revisions, then you'll see that you have made TWO edits to this post. The first edit you made was fine and so no one complained. However, your second edit undid the improvements from the previous edit... that's *your* responsibility... that's why, not one, but TWO reviewers came here to rollback your incorrect edit. To be fair to you, the timings were close, so the second edit *could* have been an accidental edit, but you would have been told that someone else was also editing the question and therefore it was still *your* responsibility to check the changes.

Comment: Anyone (or OP) has figured this out? I'm having the same issue here and all I see are comments about the editing and grammar =(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable sorting using `xDomain[firstVal, lastVal]` this will change the sorting of your data, or you can use also `lines: {xDomain[firstVal, lastVal]}` here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qYr6sv?p=preview) done with Angular-nvd3